# Get all the versions of a packge via GitHub API

Tags: github

I'm trying to get the IDs of all the versions of a private package hosted on GitHub Packages using the V4 GraphQL GitHub API. Unfortunately, I have no idea how GraphQL works and only I can't find anything helpful.

Does anyone know what should I replace the `???` below with to get what I need?

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
-H "Authorization: bearer TOKEN" \
-d '{"query":"{ user(login: \"USER\") ??? }"}' \
https://api.github.com/graphql
```